# wget 404 Error when trying to Download Mine-craft Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wget, minecraft

I'm trying to download [1.14.4 pre 6](https://launcher.mojang.com/v1/objects/d7b8f310278a5ea9efef03b4e441f12524253c5d/server.jar) Minecraft server on Ubuntu Server.

This is the full URL: https://launcher.mojang.com/v1/objects/d7b8f310278a5ea9efef03b4e441f12524253c5d/server.jar

When I do

`wget -O minecraft_server.jar https://launcher.mojang.com/v1/objects/.../server.jar`

(removed URL data to fit on one line)

or

`wget https://launcher.mojang.com/v1/objects/.../server.jar`

I also tried with curl and using sudo on them as well.

I get the ERROR

"Resolving launcher.mojang.com (launcher.mojang.com)... 13.225.66.128
Connecting to launcher.mojang.com (launcher.mojang.com)|13.225.66.128|:443... connected.
2019-07-16 01:24:35 ERROR 404: Not Found."

I've looked around on the internet at Linux mine craft server installations and they all say to use wget with that link to download it. I'm not sure if I'm just missing a option for wget or doing it completely wrong. If anyone knows if theres a way to get this to work or if there are other options to get that jar file onto my ubuntu server? any feedback is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried downloading with a browser?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I don't think Ubuntu server has a browser to download from.

Comment: From another machine?

Comment: Maybe the site was just temporarily down. I was able to download the file (using your wget command) with no problems.

Comment: @ajgringo619 I just tried it on my mint VM and it works fine as well its just not working on this Ubuntu server.